# How to iterate through each url form txt file and download multiple file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I have a txt file that contains more than 2000 the download links of various zip files. What is the best way to read text file and iterate through each line and download all files one by one. opening 2000 tabs will probably crash the pc, so i only want to download the file after first is finished.

The example of data_download.txt file is

```html
https://data.unavco.org/archive/gnss/rinex/obs/2015/001/uh010010.15d.Z
https://data.unavco.org/archive/gnss/rinex/obs/2014/365/uh013650.14d.Z
https://data.unavco.org/archive/gnss/rinex/obs/2015/002/uh010020.15d.Z
https://data.unavco.org/archive/gnss/rinex/obs/2015/006/uh010060.15d.Z
https://data.unavco.org/archive/gnss/rinex/obs/2015/004/uh010040.15d.Z
```

I use this code, but this only download the files when i click next and i have to click more then 2000 times to download each files.

```html
import tkinter as tk
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open('data_download.txt') as file:
    urls = iter([line.strip() for line in file])

def open_next():
    try:
        driver.get(next(urls))
    except StopIteration:
        print('no more urls')
        return


root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open next url', command=open_next)
btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to do it automatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through the URLs and download them one by one in a thread.

Comment: @acw1668 any example or show me how to do this?

Comment: If you already have the direct url for the zips, you don't need selenium, at all. Just use `requests` or `aiohttp`. You can download the zips in a loop by sticking your requests in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tkinter package at all.
If `driver.get(...)` will get download a file, then you can do some thing like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open('data_download.txt') as file:
    [driver.get(line.strip()) for line in file]
```

Comment: tiinter package is just to hide code from other user and give GUI interface.

Comment: in that case you should you the tkinter package. but above code should work to get the file

Comment: There are more then 2000 line, should it download one by one or all at once and freeze the browser? can requests or aiohttp will be any help here? also can i show progress like show how many have downloaded like if there are total 2000 lines then show progress bar as 4/2000 and so on.

Comment: You're using a side-effect and teaching new users to use them. It is bad practice to create an arbitrary `list comprehension` just to abuse the loop.